# putting on jumper without twisting

Tags: clothing

How can one can sure the shirt remain in place or fix it after wearing jumper (sweater), every time i wear i feel uncomfortable. I saw when i take it off, my shirt is all twisted. When we were kids, we were told to hold cuff in the hand while putting on jumper but it seem like a thing of

> old dog, new trick

. Anyone got any special hacks for not having jumper twist when wearing jumper or ways to see where it is twisted from and fix it?

Comment: What you call a "jumper" might be called something else elsewhere -- is this British, American, Indian, or some other usage?

Comment: @ZeissIkon I mean sweater

Answer (score 2):

The sleeves do twist if you do not hold them while putting your jumper on, or they move up so much that you can not easily pull them down. 
So hold your cuffs when you put your jumper on.

You also seem to suffer from the body of your shirt not being right when you take your jumper off. That you can prevent with this:
Tuck your shirt into your trousers (or your pants) and make sure those are a tight fit so the shirt does not work out.
There is at least [one website that teaches you how to tuck.](http://www.artofmanliness.com/2014/04/15/how-tuck-in-shirt/)

Some places sell shirts in different lengths, you might need to buy one which is longer and stays better tucked in.

If that is not enough, you can do as dancers do, and wear a shirt which is sewn onto underpants.

Comment: sewn into pants?

Comment: Yes, there are shirts that are sewn into underpants.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what type of shirt it is, or indeed the pullover.
No additional ideas for the cuffs, do what your mum told you! ;) But for the waist, ensure that you have a long fit shirt and have your tailor fit a "shirt grip" into the waistband of your trousers.

Not sure that I would wear a dress-shirt/shirt & collar with a pullover. I'd either go commando with just the pullover, or if I needed the warmth, I'd layer a short sleeve shirt with a close-fitting long-sleeve shirt over that, below the pullover, the sleeves ought to be close-fitting enough without being tight.

on second thoughts, you could use elastic bands if you don't fancy holding the cuffs.

Comment: All those things you mentioned in second paragraph is unknown to me. Do you have any picture to depict as I m bad with choosing clothes

Comment: 'Go commando' = do without.